# React component is rendering only once time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, jsx

I'm trying to use React with my Express backend. Currently, i'm using React as my template language.

My views are .jsx files.

```
/* Express */
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const session = require('express-session');
...
/* Express application parameters */
app
    .set('views', __dirname + '/views')
    .set('view engine', 'jsx')
    .engine('jsx', require('express-react-views').createEngine())
    .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
    .use(sessionStorage)
    .use(express.static('public'));

// Express routing defined in ./routes/index.js 
require('./routes')(app);
```

**index.js**

```
/* Express routing */
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/subscribe', require('./subscribe').get);
    app.post('/subscribe', require('./subscribe').post);
    app.get('/', require('./login').get);
    app.post('/', require('./login').post);
    app.all('/userlist', require('./home').all);
    app.get('/lobby', require('./lobby').get);
    app.get('/playdario', require('./game').get);
    app.post('/playdario', require('./game').post);
    app.all('/logout', require('./logout').all);
}
```

This is my route handler for the subscription page :

**subscribe.js**

```
exports.get = (req, res) => {
    res.render('subscribe', { 'title': 'Subscription' });
}
```

I'm trying as a test (like in React tutorial) to refresh a Clock component at each second.

**subscribe.jsx**

```
  var React = require('react');
    var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
    var DefaultLayout = require('./layouts/default');

    class Clock extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
             this.state = { date: new Date() };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerID = setInterval(
            () => this.tick(),
            1000
        );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerID);
    }

    tick() {
        this.setState({
            date: new Date()
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
            <div>
                <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
            </div>
            </DefaultLayout>
        );
      }
    }
    module.exports = Clock;
```

All of my views are composed by a default component which contains the html tags.

**default.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');

class DefaultLayout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <html>
                <head><title>{this.props.title}</title></head>
                <body>
                    {this.props.children}
                </body>
            </html>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = DefaultLayout;
```

But the problem is that the clock is displayed only one time, when I reach the page. But clock is not refreshing at all. I tried another example with a button that is changing text value placed in his state but it's not working too...

Must I use **.jsx* files in my res.render ? When i send an html file like I did at beginning of my project, i did not found how to send informations from Express through my html file like I can do with views like .twig or .jsx...

What I did wrong?

Comment: why not try react-dom's renderToString method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that `express-react-views` actually mounts the components. As per its [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views):

> This is an Express view engine which renders React components on
>   server. It renders static markup and does not support mounting those
>   views on the client.

So no components are mounted and only the markup generated is rendered. That means that `componentDidMount` is never called because the component itself is never instantiated in browser. If you want the React component to interact with elements, you'll need to render it client-side.

Comment: But in that case, how can I render my file with `res.render(...) ` ? Must I use `res.sendFile()` with a html file ? And with this, how could I pass variables through server to my html file ? Before trying to use React, I was using Twig as my template and I could sent some informations to my view with `res.render()`. This is what i'm looking for but with React...

Comment: You probably can't do it with ExpressJS. Instead you'll need to execute `ReactDOM.render` from within the page itself. You could perhaps serve the initial content with `res.render`, but you'll then need to re-render it once the page has loaded.

Comment: Then maybe I should use template engine like Jade and insert my React components as a script into the Jade view ?

Comment: Perhaps? I'm not familiar with Jade (or Express JS itself for that matter), but you'll definitely want to reserve a spot for it on your page, and then insert the components via script.

Comment: Yes I tested it and that's what I was looking for. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not re-rendering, I assume `tick()` is not triggered, because the state is updated there. Try doing the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
        this.tick,
        1000
    );
}
```

or

```
componentDidMount() {
    var self = this
    this.timerID = setInterval(
        () => self.tick(),
        1000
    );
}
```

since `this` is not in the scope of the arrow function

Comment: Tried both and did not worked :/ It's working here : [React clock example](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/amqdNA?editors=0010) but they use ReactDOM.Render...